# Sci fi movie where a killer robot wears the face of the main character

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

There's a movie, that I watched in the mid 90's, with a scene where a killer robot wears the face of the friend of the main character.

The scene I remember is on a planet e.g. the moon, and that the main character is in a white dome like structure hiding from the robots. The robot walks by with the friend's face on and peers through the little window on the door of the dome. The robot was a metal structure with long metal legs and only the face was human.

I thought it was *Screamers*, with Peter Weller, but I've just watched the whole thing and it did not happen.

Comment: Whilst this seems like quite an identifiable scene could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in anything else you may remember? For example, do you know when you saw this?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help and the link. I really wish I had more info but I was banking on it being Screamers. I remember seeing it in the mid 90s, hence it tied in nicely with my thinking. The robot was a metal structure with long metal legs and only the face was human. I know I am not helping much but if I could remember anything more concrete I'd offer it.

Comment: A white dome on the moon reminds me of *Moontrap* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moontrap), but I don't remember a stolen face scene.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I don't think it is this film either, although i hadn't heard of that so will give it a watch. The dome, from what I remember, was rather small and was a structure they were hiding in, rather than a more permanent location. I am also mindful that my memory may be distorted so the only cold hard facts I remember are the ones in my initial question

Comment: The face thing reminds me of Saturn 3, starring Kirk Douglas, Farrah Fawcett, and Harvey Keitel. At one point the robot-gone-amuck kills Keitel's character and wears his head. Not sure if the rest of the movie jives with the OP's description though. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_3)

Comment: FYI, the moon is not a planet...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per FuzzyBoots' comment in your original query, [that scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_-lE9sQTNU&feature=youtu.be&t=4158) is indeed from [MoonTrap (1989)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097911/).

<sub><sup>**Warning: NSFW for gore and hilarity**</sup></sub>

> [image]

Poor Bruce Campbell.

Comment: Yes! That is absolutely it. And after I thought id never heard of that film, obviously ive seen it at some point. Thanks for your help, the scene is exactly as I remembered it, especially the bit where they're standing over the robot

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in a picture in case the original link goes dark.

Comment: I'd forgotten this scene. Epic and unashamedly ridiculous.

Comment: Have done, thanks again. I agree this scene is indeed epic, it has stayed with me for the last 20+ years anyway!

Comment: Yep - I immediately thought "Moontrap" after reading the description. You beat me to it, though. Great movie, btw - one of my favorites. I mentioned that to Walter Koenig at a convention and he said it was one of his, too.